# Optimizing Modulo of Large Multiplication C++

Tags: c++, multiplication, modulo

I'm trying to make my program, which handles multiplications of large numbers with modulo, faster. This is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long multiply = 1;
    char x;
    while ( (x = getchar()) != '\n' )
    {
        multiply = (multiply*(x-64))%26;
    }
    if (multiply < 10)
        printf("0%d\n", multiply);
    else
        printf("%d\n", multiply);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First of all, I get a warning because you use the symbol `%d` to print `long`, probably you can just use `int` and it won't make a difference since the maximum value is 26.)

I think you could potentially improve the speed by using an unsigned integer type, since modulo is a bit simpler for unsigned integers. (It's hard to be sure just from looking at the generated assembly... https://goo.gl/LAc42f)

Comment: I made the correction and changed it to an unsigned int, but I'm still getting time limit exceeded. I don't know if it's really the speed or if it's something else making the program freeze when I upload it.

Comment: I think you could get rid of `iostream` include? iiuc there is some static initialization stuff that gets added to your program when you include that header. but it should be pretty minimal here... what is the time limit?

Comment: why do you read until "\n"? are you sure that the inputs they give you are "\n" terminated? i didn't see that in the statement. i guess it says first line... hmm...

Comment: That did the trick! Changed the condition to an isupper() and it finally worked. I knew it was something making the program stuck and not the actual speed of it after I tried a ton of algorithms haha. Thanks!

Comment: hehe no problem mate :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `getchar` is your bottleneck. You can try reading in bigger chunks at a time:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>

#define BUFFER  2048
#define OFFSET  ('A' - 1)
#define MODULUS 26

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER];
    int count, done = 0, multiply = 1;
    while (!done && (count = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFER, stdin)))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (isupper(buffer[i]))
            {
                multiply *= (buffer[i] - OFFSET);
                multiply %= MODULUS;
            }
            else
            {
                done = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%02d\n", multiply);
    return 0;
}
```

Also fixed up the `printf` and removed magic numbers.  It works with the test cases.

One item of note, if you get a result of zero after a modulus operation, then there's no point in continuing, because your product will always be zero after that, so you can do a shortcut there:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>

#define BUFFER  2048
#define OFFSET  ('A' - 1)
#define MODULUS 26

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER];
    int count, done = 0, multiply = 1;
    while (!done && multiply && (count = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFER, stdin)))
    {
        for (int i = 0; multiply && i < count; i++)
        {
            if (isupper(buffer[i]))
            {
                multiply *= (buffer[i] - OFFSET);
                multiply %= MODULUS;
            }
            else
            {
                done = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%02d\n", multiply);
    return 0;
}
```

Reading in chunks and the shortcut optimizations might be what you need to beat the time limit.